# Button click doesn't call function

Tags: c#, asp.net

in aspx file when i change the postion of button its work well but when i put it in current psitiion the click method doesnot call;
the function of click is correct

> > button4(end of codes)

```
  <div class="ui  container">
    <div runat="server" id="mydiv" class="ui form">

    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<div class="ui modal">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
        Add request
    </div>
    <div class="image content">
        <div class="ui form">
            <label>user id</label>
            <input runat="server" id="usid" type="text" />
            <label>Details</label>
            <textarea id="details" runat="server" rows="2"></textarea>
            <label>Cost</label>
            <input id="cost" runat="server" type="text" />
            <label>dead time</label>
            <input id="date" runat="server" class="ui date" type="date" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
         <asp:Button ID="Button4" class="ui positive right labeled icon button" runat="server" OnClick="Button4_Click" Text="Button" />

        <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

i use ui-semantic popup 
behind code

```
 protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            acceptance ac = new acceptance();
            ac.user_id = Convert.ToInt32(usid.Value.ToString());
            ac.work_id = mywork.id;
            ac.detail = details.Value.ToString();
            ac.dead_time = Convert.ToDateTime(date.Value.ToString());
            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var hj = from i in db.acceptances where i.user_id == ac.user_id && i.work_id == ac.work_id select i;
            if (hj.Count() > 0)
            {
                Exception c = new Exception("this user alredy accepted");
                throw c;
            }
            var maxValue = db.acceptances.Max(x => x.id);
            ac.id = maxValue + 1;
            db.acceptances.InsertOnSubmit(ac);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl er = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Master.FindControl("error");
            HtmlGenericControl al = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Master.FindControl("alert");
            al.Visible = true;
            er.Visible = true;
            er.InnerText = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is the button in in a `form` tag?

Comment: show how do you define Button4_Click in the code behind. Also answer @Dr.Fre question

Comment: yes . i use master page and ContentPlaceHolder is in form tag;@Dr.Fre

Comment: the behind code is call if the button is not in this position @mybirthname

Comment: Try to put entire code inside form tag

Comment: the code is in the form tag by using in master page @UJS